# Spark SBT compilation issue

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

in my compilation even though i am placing twitter jar files in the src/main/resources folder ,but SBT compilation is not picking them up and compiles and package without errors but at run time gives me error as "class not found twitterUtils"

my question is why SBT is not including the jar files from resource folder in the compilation ?

people are telling me to do all these complex steps of getting the Git utility and then doing a sbt assembly which I did but since iam behind proxy Git is not working even though all the http_proxy setup. 
I have also tried putting these twitter jar files in the CLASSPATH with no luck.
I am stuck with this issue so any help is highly appreciated.
please see the details below

```
[root@hadoop1 TwitterPopularTags]# pwd
/root/TwitterPopularTags
[root@hadoop1 TwitterPopularTags]# sbt compile
[info] Set current project to TwitterPopularTags (in build file:/root/TwitterPopularTags/)
[info] Updating {file:/root/TwitterPopularTags/}twitterpopulartags...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /root/TwitterPopularTags/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Total time: 14 s, completed Sep 16, 2016 9:55:20 AM
[root@hadoop1 TwitterPopularTags]# sbt package
[info] Set current project to TwitterPopularTags (in build file:/root/TwitterPopularTags/)
[info] Packaging /root/TwitterPopularTags/target/scala-2.11/twitterpopulartags_2.11-1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 16, 2016 9:56:20 AM
[root@hadoop1 TwitterPopularTags]# spark-submit /root/TwitterPopularTags/target/scala-2.11/twitterpopulartags_2.11-1.0.jar
16/09/16 09:57:06 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.2
16/09/16 09:57:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/16 09:57:06 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/09/16 09:57:06 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/09/16 09:57:06 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 53967.
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.100.44.17:57877]
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 57877.
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-47a89077-0926-447c-ada7-fdb4a9aa1b83
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.5 MB
16/09/16 09:57:07 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.100.44.17:4040
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-d56628b6-fdbf-4d89-bbd2-a96603000607/httpd-ee499eb3-00ae-4276-b163-423e3b81f0b4
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:56067
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 56067.
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/root/TwitterPopularTags/target/scala-2.11/twitterpopulartags_2.11-1.0.jar at http://10.100.44.17:56067/jars/twitterpopulartags_2.11-1.0.jar with timestamp 1474034228091
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 49715.
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 49715
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:49715 with 511.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 49715)
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/09/16 09:57:08 WARN DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
16/09/16 09:57:08 INFO EventLoggingListener: Logging events to hdfs:///spark-history/local-1474034228122
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/twitter/TwitterUtils$
        at dot.state.fl.us.PrintTweets$.main(PrintTweets.scala:29)
        at dot.state.fl.us.PrintTweets.main(PrintTweets.scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

> my question is why SBT is not including the jar files from resource folder in the compilation ?

Because that's not what resource folder is for. If you want to manage the dependencies manually, [put them into `lib` folder instead](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies). But in this case you also need to do the same with all dependencies of those dependencies, their dependencies, etc. Using managed dependencies, as described in the linked documentation, is a much better idea in general.

Comment: hi Alexey I am not seeing the linked documentation can you please post link here  ?    why isn't SBT downloading the twitter dependent jar files since its in the list of dependencies in the build.sbt file "spark-streaming-twitter ?         please see  below  "libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % sparkVersion
)
"

Comment: sorry I found the link never mind but my question remains .  why the twitter jars are not being downloaded even though they are in the list of the dependencies ? or maybe they are being downloaded and my class not found error is something else?

Comment: i placed my twitter jar files in the lib folder and clean-compile-package but still getting  error on not finding "twitterUtils"                                      [root@hadoop1 lib]# pwd
/root/TwitterPopularTags/lib
[root@hadoop1 lib]# ls -ltr
total 360
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60808 Sep 16 11:18 twitter4j-stream-4.0.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 290456 Sep 16 11:18 twitter4j-core-4.0.4.ziptwitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14115 Sep 16 11:18 dstream-twitter_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[root@hadoop1 lib]#

Comment: I added the twitter4j dependencies but still no luck  please help                libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % sparkVersion,
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "3.0.3",
  "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "3.0.3"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
 "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
)